# The method 'didAddToChannel' was called on null

Tags: dart, aqueduct

When I start the server I receive this error

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'didAddToChannel' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null Tried calling: didAddToChannel()

this is my code

```
@override
  Controller get entryPoint {
    final router = Router();

    // Handles any route that starts with /file/
    router.route("/file/*").link(() => FileController('/'));

    router.route('/filiais/:id').link(() => FilialController());
    router.route('/filiais').link(() => FilialController());
  }
```

I edit my ApplicationChannel class and receive this error. What can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error, I forgot the `return`

it's a simple error, but I spend minutes

I put

```
return router;
```

and work

Comment: this makes 2 of us :)